# How to programmatically convert .rm (RealPlayer Media) file to MP3 or another format?

Tags: audio, directshow, directshow.net, transcoding, realplayer

I would like to convert `.rm` (RealPlayer Media) file to MP3 or another format?
First, I successfully managed that using [VLC](http://wiki.videolan.org/VLC_command-line_help) but the quality was not good. Then I tried the [Real Alternative codec](http://www.free-codecs.com/download/Real_Alternative.htm) with DirectShow, this also worked ok, but then I found that [the codec is no longer developed](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RealPlayer#Real_Alternative) because RealNetworks sued the developer.

Now, I have installed the RealPlayer and I am trying to use it's DirectShow filters to convert `.rm` to `.mp3` but without success:( (Actually after adding RealPlayer Transcode filter and choosing a file the [GraphStudio](http://blog.monogram.sk/janos/tools/monogram-graphstudio/) crashes.)

Is there a legal way to programmatically convert `.rm` file to another format? How to make RealPlayer to programmatically convert files? Do you have any hints or examples, how to use RealPlayer Transcode filter? (I am new to DirectShow.)

**UPDATE to make the question more concrete:** How can I list implemented interfaces and its members of RealPlayer Transcode filter? I have not found any documentation:( (The GraphStudio says it has 0 pins and just common properties.)

Comment: This does not look like a programming problem.  I suggest http://superuser.com

Comment: DirectShow is not a programming problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to build a DirectShow graph to read and decode `.rm`, then compress audio into `MP3` and write it into a file. This is similar to recompressing an AVI file, described in some detail on MSDN: [Recompressing an AVI File](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd377501%28v=VS.85%29.aspx). You just have audio without video there, and the container formats are different.

UPDATE: There is no way to reliably list implemented interfaces in COM. Sometimes you can find this out by checking the type library, however a lot of DirectShow filters are coming without it. Typically, you need an SDK header file from the filter vendor to get a definition of implemented so called 'private' interfaces.

Comment: I managed that for Real Alternative, but not for RealPlayer Transcode filter. Please see update of my question.